# Not reading from file

Tags: c++

I want to read each word from a file. It opens the file but it does not enter the while loop

```
  string x;
        ifstream inFile ("test.txt");
        if (!inFile) {
            cout << "Unable to open file";
            exit(1); // terminate with error
        }

        while (inFile >> x) {
            cout << "hi" << endl;
        }
        cout << "hsiwsdsc" << endl;

        inFile.close();
```

Comment: What are the contents of the file and what is your output?

Comment: And how is this related to Xcode?

Comment: Try printing `x` to see if it read anything.

Comment: Also, if printing x produces nothing, you could use some of the built in `ifstream`/`ios` functions to test the state of the stream ,e.g. `bad()`, `fail()`, `eof()` etc  see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking to see if the file is even open, my friend. Check out this code:

```
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream input("example.txt");

    if (input.is_open()) {
        while (input.good()) {
            std::getline(input, line);
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
        }
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open stinky file" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```